# How to remove the last space?

Tags: python-3.x, range

I need to select every third letter out of a sentence (starting from the first letter), and print out those letters with spaces in between them.

So the program should look like this:

```
Message? cxohawalkldflghemwnsegfaeap
c h a l l e n g e
```

I have written the following code:

```
n = input("Message? ")
for i in range(0,len(n),3):
  print(n[i],end=" ")
```

However, I am getting a space at the end of the output. Please help me out. I am quite new to python.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly printing the output, you can insert the chunks into one variable and remove the last character of the input.

```
n = input("Message? ")
x = ""
for i in range(0,len(n),3):
  x = x + n[i] + " "
x = x[:-1]
print(x,end="")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use slicing with step argument.

**Ex:**

```
s = 'cxohawalkldflghemwnsegfaeap'
print(" ".join(s[::3]))
```

**Output:**

```
c h a l l e n g e
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` function, it automatically removes the last space.

```
n = input("Message? ")
print(" ".join(n[i] for i in range(0, len(n), 3)))
```

A simple way to understand how it works.

```
n = input("Message? ")
letters = []
for i in range(0, len(n), 3):
    letters.append(n[i])
print(" ".join(letters))
```

Answer (score 0):

`*` symbol is use to print the list elements in a single line with space

```
n = input("Message? ")
ans = ""
for i in range(0,len(n),3):
    ans += n[i]

print(*ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution:

```
s = 'cxohawalkldflghemwnsegfaeap'

print(*s[::3])
```

Output:

```
c h a l l e n g e
```